# In stochastic calculus, what is the differentiation of $W(t)$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I am very confused dealing $dW(t)$, what is it? $W(t)$ is nowhere differentiable, we cannot write $W'(t)~dt$, but $dW(t)$ is a notation often used in my professor's notes.

Comment: Note that $W(t)$ has quadratic variance meaning the process does not deviate much from $y=\sqrt{t}$. So we can write $(dW(t))^2 = dt $

Comment: The usual interpretation of $dW(t)dW(t)=dt$ is the quadratic variation $[W,W](t)=t$. Does anybody know what they could mean with $t_1$ and $t_2$?

Comment: Contrarily to what is sometimes asserted, it is **not** recommended to use notations such as $(dW(t))^2=dt$ if one wants to get any understanding of the subject. Re the notation $dW(t)$ itself, the whole object of Itô's calculus is to give a rigorous meaning to so-called stochastic integrals $$\int_0^tX_sdW(s)$$ for suitable stochastic processes $(X_t)$ eventhough, as you note, the paths $t\mapsto W(t)$ are almost surely non differentiable.

Comment: @EdwardWang Indeed, would you have examples of sources using the notation $dW(t_1)dW(t_2)$?

Comment: @parsiad No idea why your answer was downvoted.

Comment: @Did: I would guess it was because I did not explicitly discuss $dW(t_1)dW(t_2)$. I will undelete it (in case it is useful to OP) and bear the brunt of the downvote :-)

Comment: @Did $dW_1(t)dW_2(t) = 0$ oh sorry, my professor means the cross variation, or quadratic covariance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you see an SDE of the form
$$
dX_{s}=a(s,X_{s})ds+b(s,X_{s})dW(s),
$$
just remember that this is simply a "short form" for
$$
X_{s}=x+\int_{t}^{s}a(u,X_{u})du+\int_{t}^{s}b(u,X_{u})dW(u)
$$
where $x$ is the initial condition at time $t$.

That is, the only place $dW(u)$ appears is in an Ito integral, whose definition you might already be familiar with. No derivatives are considered.

**Addendum**: While $dW(t)dW(t)=dt$ is just short form to describe the quadratic variation of the process $[W,W](t)=t$, I am not sure what the notation $dW(t_1)dW(t_2)$ could mean.

Comment: @downvoter Why the downvote? The answer addresses the part of the question that one can understand.